# Video created with ffmpeg does not playing in Windows media player

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

Issue: Video is not playing with Windows Media Player while its successfully playing with VLC player, Google Chrome browser.

Below are the details that I am using:
1. npm "fluent-ffmpeg" version: "2.1.2" in node application.
2. node version 8.11.3.
3. FFmpeg version: 20161230-6993bb4 downloaded from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds.
4. Set path to ffmpeg.exe to in path on system environment.
5. Here is the sample code.

```
let command = new ffmpeg({ source: 'rtsp://192.168.2.198/cam0_1' }), fileName = 'abc.mp4';

// Record video from camera.
command.inputFPS(20)
  .duration(10)
  .on('start', function () {
    console.log('Recording started.', ('File: ' + fileName));
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('Recording completed.', ('File: ' + fileName));
  })
  .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('An error occurs while recording.', ('File: ' + fileName), err.message, stdout, stderr);
  })
  .format('mp4')
  .save(fileName);
```

Comment: Run `ffprobe` on the outputed mp4 file and show us the file's encoded properties.  Windows media player has a very narrow codec compatibility list.

Comment: Thanks for replying, here is the link to get details of properties getting form ffprobe:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0fa0131c58826d0f330eca60fd1f549b20190117145038/eca858724f9c40f5ea1155db9bee581320190117145038/fac8fe